I put a comment jesus is god without meaning it
I put a comment on instagram "jesus is god" just to troll , I'm a muslim and I did it out of stupidity, I deleted the comment right after
Did I commit shirk? I hope allah forgives me

Kufr done in jest is still Kufr.

It is not shirk necessarily, as far as I can say:

لَيْسَ عَلَيْكُمْ جُنَاحٌ فِيمَا أَخْطَأْتُمْ بِهِ وَ لَكِنْ مَا
تَعَمَّدَتْ قُلُوبُكُمْ
And there is no blame upon you for that in which you have erred but
[only for] what your hearts intended

‌But I just cannot imagine what was going on in your mind when you did it, so it is difficult to say anything and you should judge it on your own side. For example if it was mocking (with bad intention) it is still forbidden as Allah warns:

يَحْذَرُ الْمُنَافِقُونَ أَنْ تُنَزَّلَ عَلَيْهِمْ سُورَةٌ
تُنَبِّئُهُمْ بِمَا فِي قُلُوبِهِمْ قُلِ اسْتَهْزِءُوا إِنَّ اللَّهَ
مُخْرِجٌ مَا تَحْذَرُونَ . وَ لَئِنْ سَأَلْتَهُمْ لَيَقُولُنَّ
إِنَّمَا كُنَّا نَخُوضُ وَ نَلْعَبُ قُلْ أَبِاللَّهِ وَ آيَاتِهِ وَ
رَسُولِهِ كُنْتُمْ تَسْتَهْزِءُونَ
The Hypocrites are afraid lest a Sura should be sent down about them,
showing them what is (really passing) in their hearts. Say: 'Mock ye!
But verily Allah will bring to light all that ye fear (should be
revealed). If thou dost question them, they declare (with emphasis):
'We were only talking idly and in play.' Say: 'Was it at Allah, and
His Signs, and His Messenger, that ye were mocking?

This is Kufr (Hypocrites are worse than common Kuffar), but I can hardly imagine this is true about you, as hypocrites are not afraid of how Allah will judge them. Maybe it was a sudden instantaneous false decision. This can be instantaneous Kufr, and this is not uncommon among Muslims, but you can repent and decide firmly not to repeat it, and try to stay away from situations which might put you on similar psychological states to do what you did. All that we do here is to show you people will not be easily considered Mushrik. For example consider a mother who loses her kid in an accident, she might say Shirk and Kufr out of sadness, an no one will consider her a mushrik, but all on her around should try to talk with her, inviting her to patience, not to lose her hope in Allah, and to recall her of what Dunya is in our belief system, and etc. Similarly, someone who is so angry will say Shirk and Kufr out of madness, and people on his around should enjoin him to what is right, and forbid him from what is wrong, and he should try to once again achieve the control of his psyche in the stormy sea with violent emotional and psychological waves hitting him from all around.
